# Unable to locate credentials when running airflow in docker

Tags: docker-compose, airflow, aws-credentials

I run airflow in docker and has volumes setting as

```
- ~/.aws:/usr/local/airflow/.aws:rw
```

I can see my local ~/.aws/credentials has:

```
[some_profile]
aws_access_key_id = xxxxx
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxx
```

and I can see the same content in airflow worker `/usr/local/airflow/.aws/credentials`, and `aws configure list` can return expected results like:

```
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                 datalake              env    ['xxx_PROFILE', 'AWS_PROFILE']
access_key     ****************xxxx shared-credentials-file
secret_key     ****************xxxx shared-credentials-file
    region                <not set>             None    None
```

and cmd like `aws s3 ls` works locally. However for

```
sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
assumed_role = sts_client.assume_role(RoleArn=role_arn, RoleSessionName='xxx')
```

it throws:

```
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be here.
When you're declaring `[some_profile]` for the credentials file, it should be like this:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = xxxxx
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxx
```

There must be a `default` profile in your credentials.

If that doesn't work, you can always set the credentials manually

First, set the profile

```
[some_profile]
aws_access_key_id = xxxxx
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxx
```

Then, your Python code should look like this

```py
os.environ['AWS_PROFILE'] = "some_profile"
os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = "some_region"

s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='some_region')
```

Comment: Thanks @strider. Seems the container worker looks up `default` profile. If I set 
```
os.environ['AWS_PROFILE'] = "some_profile"
os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = "some_region"
```
It can look up some_profile. Is there a way not to change the Python but to use the profile I specified?
I tried AWS_PROFILE=some_profile or put profile in docker compose but not work.